# How to fix this dropup menu in IE?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This drop up notification menu doesn't work in IE 11: https://sharebootstrap.com/demo/docu/

How to fix this code in IE 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-footer .dropdown-menu
{
   top: auto!important;
}
```

I think it will solve your problem. 
Otherwise give a class then give `top: auto!important;`